# SonicWall TZ210 decode exp file

Tags: router, password-recovery

I have the backup file of the Sonicwall TZ210 but lost the admin password.

The backup file is .exp, is there a way to decode it using windows pc?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete solution, but a start. With Linux, you can use this to decode the dump:

```
base64 -d your-backup.exp | sed 's/&/\n/g'
```

Or use this Perl Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use MIME::Base64;

local($/) = undef; # slurp

my $decoded = decode_base64(<STDIN>);
$decoded =~ s/&/\n/gms;
print $decoded;
```

You will find the password line and might be able to brute-force it with john the ripper (http://www.openwall.com/john/). There is no easier way here.

Answer (score 0):

A PowerShell script can decode the file to readable text on a Windows system, but, as noted by another answer, this does not address password decryption:

```
Function SonicWall_Exp2Txt ($Exp)
{
  $Txt = $Exp -ireplace ".exp$", ".txt"
  # Create temporary file names.
  $Tmp = "." + $(get-date -uformat %s) + "."
  $TmpTxt = $Txt -replace ".txt$", $($Tmp + ".txt")
  $TmpExp = $TmpTxt -replace ".txt$", ".exp"
  # Show input/output file names while processing.
  Write-Host $("`n" + $Exp + "`n--> " + $Txt)
  # Remove two "&" characters at the end of an .exp file before decoding it.
  ( Get-Content $Exp ) -replace ".{2}$" |
    Out-File -Encoding default -FilePath $TmpExp
  # certutil.exe -decode /?
  # Usage:
  #   CertUtil [Options] -decode InFile OutFile
  #   Decode Base64-encoded file
  # Note:
  #   certutil.exe aborts if OutFile already exists.
  & certutil.exe -decode $TmpExp $TmpTxt
  # Reformat the decoded file with line breaks to make it more readable.  It
  # is also possible to recode the output file with Out-File -Encoding set
  # to unicode, utf7, utf8, utf32, ascii, bigendianunicode, default, or oem.
  ( Get-Content $TmpTxt ) -replace '\&', "`n" |
    Out-File -Encoding utf8 -FilePath $Txt
  # Remove the temporary files.
  Remove-Item $TmpExp
  Remove-Item $TmpTxt
}

# Get-ChildItem returns a scalar if one .exp file exists or an array if more
# than one .exp file is present.  Force $Files to an array value to avoid
# error if only one file exists as scalars do not have a Count method.
#
$Files = @( Get-ChildItem "." -Filter "*.exp" )
For ($Loop=0; $Loop -lt $Files.Count; $Loop++)
{
  SonicWall_Exp2Txt $Files[$Loop].FullName
}
```

An example of invocation when the script is saved as ***exp2txt.ps1***:

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command exp2txt.ps1 <NUL
```

Attribution:  [This thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/465032-convert-a-sonicwall-config-file-to-a-readable-text-file) inspired the aforementioned script which was written to potentially facilitate identifying save file differences.